# Adobe Digital Editions - Only the Cover Pages on all E-books are Displaying - pages blank

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, intel-graphics, ebook, epub

Fresh install of Adobe Digital Editions.  I deleted all folders (program data / app data) prior to the reinstall. No change.  I've never used this app on this computer before.  It didn't work on initial install.  This app worked correctly on my older laptop.

I have tried several different e-books, in both ePub and PDF format. The cover pages load, but when I scroll down all the pages are blank. When I download books they are correctly added to the library.

I discovered that with the PDFs, and not ePub, if I change the size of the page in any way (fit width, 150% zoom) then I will see that one page. So I can scroll down blindly, change the size, and read the one page. It's a very painful way to read a book.

No other problems with any applications on this computer.  Standard settings, computer is 4 months old.

Windows 10, auto-updates.
(I haven't installed Feature Update version 20H2)
HP Pavilion laptop
Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7
Intel® Iris® Xᵉ Graphics

Comment: I solved the problem by installing the free Bluefire Reader.  It works perfectly.  It asks for the Adobe ID for protect content when you first launch the program, one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing the free Bluefire Reader. It works perfectly. It asks for the Adobe ID for protected content when you first launch the program, one time.

I thought this might be related to Intel's new iRISx graphics.  Maybe it is.

There were no replies here, or on Adobe's community forum.